# Javascript regex to find and concatenating the particular strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

`This is a demo from "Java script". This Demo uses "Regex"`
from the above string i want to take the words between `""` and concatenate it.Between Both the words i want to put `+` symbol. I tried with java regex but i want to do it with Javascript Regex. My final answer should be `Java scripr+Regex`.

Comment: You have tried it with Java Regex? Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = 'This is a demo from "Java script". This Demo uses "Regex"';
var r = s.match(/"([^"]*)"/g).join('+');
//=> "Java script"+"Regex"
```

#### UPDATE:

```
s.replace(/.*?"([^"]*)"([^"]*)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {return $2!=""? $1+'+':$1});
//+> Java script+Regex
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But i don't want to get the "" also. I just want the words and the + symbol

Answer (score 0):

Somply you can use this :

```
var s='This is a demo from "Java script". This Demo uses "Regex"';
var reg=/\"(.*?)\"/g;
var result=s.match(reg).join('+').replace(/"/g,"");
console.log(result);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/fc8hc/1/)**

OR

You can use something like this :

```
var s='This is a demo from "Java script". This Demo uses "Regex"';
var reg=/\"(.*?)\"/g;
var result="";
s.match(reg).forEach( function(a){  
                                   if(result!="")
                                        result+="+";
                                    result+=a.replace(/\"/g,"");
                                   });

console.log(result);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/LGr6L/)**